# Bluetooth LE scanning in background

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making an app about scanning BLE devices in **background mode** and  send devices list to server every minute

`private let uuid = CBUUID(string: "DEC18772-CCC0-462D-92FB-F5C823537895")`

`self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [uuid], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : true])`

In the plist file

```
    <array>
        <string>bluetooth-central</string>
        <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
    </array>
```

I use a timer to send device list to server after 60 secs

`var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimedCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

but when I make the app to background mode, everything seems to be paused, the timer and didDiscover call back don't work

Is there anything missing to make the app run in background mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing a couple of problems with what you are trying to do:

1. A `Timer` simply doesn't fire while your app is suspended; execution with a specific period is not a supported background mode on iOS.
2. You can't use `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey` while scanning in the background.

As you have opted in to Bluetooth background mode in your Info.plist, assuming that the user grants Bluetooth background permission, you will receive a `didDiscover` delegate callback each time a *new device* is seen that is advertising the specified service (`DEC18772-CCC0-462D-92FB-F5C823537895`).

You can report the discovery of this device to your server in this callback.

You will not receive any additional delegate discovery callbacks for that device while your app remains in the background.

Comment: Sorry but I dont' know why CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey can not use in background?

Comment: Because [that's the rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html). Presumably allowing duplicate notifications would lead to excessive background execution and have an adverse impact on battery life and device performance for the foreground app.